# MATLAB - How to cut mesh along surface of given formula?

Tags: matlab, formula, mesh, surface

I need to write a function in Matlab which cuts the mesh along the surface made by given formula. The function takes as parameters - (V,F,A,B,C,D) where: 
`V`- stores the indexes of vertexes
`F`- stores the values of vertexes
`V and F` forms the mesh, which needs to be cut 
`A,B,C,D` are the factors of the surface given by formula: `Ax+By+Cz+D=0`
All the parameters above are known
The function needs to return V1,F1,V2,F2 where:
`V1,F1` keep the data of the first cut part, 
 `V2,F2` keep the data of the second cut part. 
Then the only thing I need to do is plot them using:

```matlab
figure;
trimesh(F1,V1(:,1),V1(:,2),V1(:,3));
figure;
trimesh(F2,V2(:,1),V2(:,2),V2(:,3));
```

I completely do not know how I should start it. I would be grateful for any answers.

Comment: Refreshing comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688232/check-which-side-of-a-plane-points-are-on). I think it covers your problem as stated without any need for alterations for the fact that you have a mesh.

Comment: did you check the link? Did it answer your question?